# XSRF and double submit cookie JWT alternative - is this implementation safe?

Tags: http, security, jwt, csrf

I was looking into HTTP security for my REST API and I was hoping to make it more secure by using the [Double Submit Cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) pattern but I'm pretty sure that I'm actually doing something similar already (totally by accident).

This is my flow:

1. Client makes a POST request to server with username and password.
2. Server responds with a JWT token.
3. Client saves the token into a cookie.
4. On subsequent requests the client reads the token cookie and places the token into the Authorization header (I'm pretty sure that this step is equivelent to the double cookie submit technique).
5. The server authenticates the user based on a valid token in the authorization header.

Now this isn't 100% equivelent as the server isn't checking that the cookie and HTTP header match (this would be trivial to add if I needed to).

Is what I have so far sufficient to block a XSRF attack or should I go with adding a `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie too?

Comment: I think this implementation is equivalent to double-submit-cookie and is safe to prevent CSRF attack. Also, this is a very clean solution when JWT token is used. However, as @mevdschee mentioned, JWT token content is exposed to attacker, as it must not be HttpOnly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be secure against XSRF attacks, but the way it sounds, you are not secure against XSS attacks. For protection against XSS attacks you need to also store a secret in a HttpOnly cookie.

Comment: But then his client won’t be able to read the cookie value to attach to the Header Authorization. So we’re back to square one.

Comment: I feel JSON Web Tokens are most suitable to cross domain boundaries (in a single-sign-on solution) or to otherwise obtain a session token. Session tokens in HttpOnly cookies are best to securely execute series of authenticated requests. Double submit and/or XSFR tokens in form fields should be used to protect against XSRF. I would not try to mix the different security goals in one single solution.